# NullReferenceException while getting data from navigation property in web-api 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nullreferenceexception

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` while trying to fetch data from navigation property.

I am trying to display as **JSon** a data from navigation property 'EventImage'. Even if element is inside property and everything is referenced I am getting null reference exception. I have queried DB and i got expected result, but when I am invoking controller's [get] action method, just null reference exception appears. As i guess even if there is no suitable element and because of one-to-zero-or-one relationship I should achieve 'EventImage : null' as JSon result.

**Domain model:**

```
public class EventDetail
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Key, ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventDetailId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No information")]
    public string EventLocalization { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date),
     DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
         NullDisplayText = "No information")]
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No information")]
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual EventImage EventImage { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventPrice> EventPrices { get; set; }
}

public class EventImage
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Key, ForeignKey("EventDetail")]
    public int EventImageId { get; set; }

    public string EventImageBase64 { get; set; }

    public virtual EventDetail EventDetail { get; set; }
}
```

**Logical model:**

```
public class SingleEventDetail
{
    public int EventDetailId { get; set; }

    public string EventLocalization { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }

    public string EventDescription { get; set; }

    public string EventImage { get; set; }
}

public class EventImage
{
    public int EventImageId { get; set; }

    public string EventImageBase64 { get; set; }
}
```

**Method I'm invoking inside controller**

```
public override SingleEventDetail GetById(int id)
    {
        var eventDetail = _eventDetailRepository.GetAll().Select(e => new SingleEventDetail
        {
            EventDetailId = e.EventDetailId,
            EventDate = e.EventDate,
            EventLocalization = e.EventLocalization,
            EventDescription = e.EventDescription,
            EventPrices =
                _eventDetailRepository.GetById(id)
                    .EventPrices.Select(ep => new EventPriceForSingleEventDetail
                    {
                        Amount = ep.Amount,
                        Currency = ep.Currency,
                        IsFullPrice = ep.IsFullPrice
                    }).ToList(),
            EventImage = e.EventImage.EventImageBase64
        }).SingleOrDefault(e => e.EventDetailId == id);

        return eventDetail;
    }
```

_eventDetailRepository.GetAll()

```
public IEnumerable<EventDetail> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.EventDetail.ToList();
    }
```

_eventDetailRepository.GetById(int id)

```
public EventDetail GetById(int id)
    {
        return _context.EventDetail.ToList().SingleOrDefault(c => c.EventDetailId == id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. Lazy loading doesn't work for this particular 'EventImage' navigation property but i have no idea why.
I have changed method _eventDetailRepository.GetById(int id) into method with eager loagind and everything works fine now.

```
public EventDetail GetById(int? id)
    {
        return _context.EventDetail.Include(e => e.EventPrices).Include(e => e.EventImage).SingleOrDefault(e => e.EventDetailId == id);
    }
```